# Alice referred Bob (or Carol?) to Carol (or Bob?)

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure

Say Bob wanted to ask Alice some question, but Alice asked Bob to find Carol for an answer. When talking to Carol, which one is correct?

1. "**Hi, Alice referred me to you / Hi, I was referred to you by Alice**"
2. "**Hi, Alice referred you to me / Hi, you were referred to me by Alice**"

i.e. the ordering of Bob and Carol in the sentence when using "refer" as the verb.

Please also provide another verb for the other ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of those formations are acceptable in spoken English.

**In writing, or in a more formal setting**, for example when talking to a Doctor, or a respected stranger — the first choice “referred me to you” is better because it carries a higher sense of respect for C.

(This is because C is not being implied or assumed to do something.)

If you’re used to a language where you use a formal word like “Vous/Sie/Usted” for respected strangers, this is the same idea.

However, this is a subtle point. In many situations, like in a professional office environment where A, B and C all work for the same company or department, choice #1 is quite acceptable.

Comment: Wow thank you! An amazing word "refer" is. I was expecting either one but not both to be correct. Wish other words like "pay" is the same: "I pay $100 to you" is the same as "You pay $100 to me" :)